# Accept/Ignore SSL certificate in Chrome browser

Tags: java, selenium, ssl, chrome-options

I am having this problem with `ChromeOptions` class in Java. When implementing it in my code it doesn't contain some of the methods that I need to Accept/Ignore SSL certificate in Chrome browser. Methods like `.setCapability` so I can pass in it `CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);`.

Example:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
```

... where `setCapability` is being marked as a mistake by Eclipse, and it says

```
The method setCapability(String, boolean) is undefined for the type ChromeOptions
```

Comment: Make sure that you have proper dependencies on [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html#setCapability-java.lang.String-boolean-) framework

Comment: How to make sure that I am using the right one? Could you please explain to me?

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer in his thread, but I think Nikolai's suggestion is:

- can you check you have the correct import in this class? `import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;`
- what is the Selenium version you are using in your pom.xml file? Ex:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: the Selenium version is the same> <version>3.141.59</version>.

Comment: OK, and the import at the beginning of the class is
`import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;` or maybe `import org.openqa.selenium.remote.*;`?

Comment: Yes, totally the same-> import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType; I kind of find out what's the problem. It looks like Chrome version above 80 can not accept or ignore the SSL certificate- I still don't know the reason, but I'll downgrade Chrome and try again to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Robot class to accept it. For me it works every time I have to deal with this kind of pop-ups.

```
    Robot r = new Robot();
    // use tab to move to desired button
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

    //than use enter to click it
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: It is not a pop-up, There is nothing to click on. It should accept/ignore the SSL certificate and continue automaticaly.